Cgi script doesnt write in log file with Apache
I'm trying to execute a CGI script using Apache2 on my server (running Debian). The script is supposed to perform some operations and log its progress to /tmp/cgi_errors.log. When I access the script via the browser, i can see successful messages, indicating that the script is executing. However, the log file remains empty no matter what I try.
I have managed to write the file thanks to
sudo -u www-data bash -c 'echo "$(date) - Test from command line" >> /tmp/cgi_errors.log'
What I'm trying to achieve:
Execute a CGI script that logs its execution steps to a log file.
Ensure that the log file is populated with the expected output for debugging purposes.
What I've done so far:
CGI Script (/usr/lib/cgi-bin/trigger_script.cgi):
#!/bin/bash

# Print the Content-Type header required for CGI
echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
echo ""

LOG_FILE="/tmp/test_output.log"

# Test 1: Basic echo with redirection
echo "test1: Writing to file using echo with > redirection" >> $LOG_FILE

# Test 2: Using printf (more control over formatting)
printf "test2: Writing to file using printf\n" >> $LOG_FILE

# Test 3: Using tee to write to file and standard output
echo "test3: Writing using tee" | tee -a $LOG_FILE

# Test 4: Using a Here document (<<) to append multiple lines
cat <<EOL >> $LOG_FILE
test4: Writing multiple lines using a Here document
Line 2 for test4
EOL

# Test 5: Using file descriptors (exec)
exec 3>> $LOG_FILE  # Open file descriptor 3 for writing
echo "test5: Writing using file descriptor 3" >&3
exec 3>&-  # Close the file descriptor

# Test 6: Using `echo` with noclobber option (to prevent overwriting if file exists)
set -o noclobber
echo "test6: Writing with noclobber (no overwrite)" >> $LOG_FILE || echo "Failed to write test6"
set +o noclobber  # Turn off noclobber

# Test 7: Writing to a file using dd
echo "test7: Writing using dd" | dd of=$LOG_FILE bs=1 seek=$(stat --format=%s $LOG_FILE) conv=notrunc

# Test 8: Using printf with file descriptor
exec 4>> $LOG_FILE
printf "test8: Writing with printf and file descriptor\n" >&4
exec 4>&-

# Output success message
echo "CGI script executed successfully, check $LOG_FILE for output."



File Permissions:
theo@vps-xxx:~$ sudo ls -lart / | grep tmp 
drwxrwxrwt  11 root root         12288 Oct  9 12:09 tmp

theo@vps-xxx:~$ sudo ls -lart /tmp | grep cgi
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    2420 Oct  9 10:58 cgi_errors.log

theo@vps-xxx:~$ sudo ls -lart /usr/lib | grep cgi 
drwxr-xr-x   2 www-data www-data    4096 Oct  9 12:12 cgi-bin

theo@vps-xxx:~$ sudo ls -lart /usr/lib/cgi-bin | grep test
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data    1428 Oct  9 12:12 test.cgi

Apache Configuration (/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf):
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # CGI setup
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

Enabled CGI Module in Apache:
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo systemctl restart apache2

Accessed the script via the browser:
http :// mydomain .com/cgi-bin/trigger_script.cgi
When I access the script via the browser, i can see successful messages but nothing in logs file...
Attempted Logging Methods:
Used echo and redirected output to the log file.
Tried using stdbuf to prevent output buffering.
Used tee to write output to both the browser and the log file.
Added set -x and exec to capture all executed commands and errors.
Verified Apache and System Logs:
Checked /var/log/apache2/error.log and /var/log/apache2/access.log for any errors related to the script. Found nothing indicative.
Monitored /tmp/cgi_errors.log the file remains empty.
Tested Writing to Different Log Locations:
Tried logging to /var/log/cgi_errors.log with appropriate permissions.
Still, the log file remains empty.
Checked for Security Restrictions:
Verified that AppArmor is not enforcing any profiles that could block logging.
SELinux is not active on the system.
Summary of the Issue:
When I access the script via the browser, i can see the successful messages,
Despite correct file permissions and ownership, the script does not write to the log file when executed via Apache.
The log file remains empty, making it difficult to debug the script's behavior under Apache.
My Question:
Why is the CGI script not writing to /tmp/cgi_errors.log when executed via Apache, despite having correct permissions and ownership?
How can I get the script to log its output to the file when run as a CGI script through Apache?
Additional Information:
Apache runs under the www-data user.
The /tmp directory has the correct permissions (drwxrwxrwt).
Other CGI scripts (simpler ones) exhibit the same behavior.
There are no errors in Apache's error logs related to the script.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

See apache 2.4 won't serve from /tmp and Where apache's /tmp located?.

solved thanks! @pjh
